# how to call app.component.ts after login successful

Tags: ionic-framework

After Successful login, I'm storing Employee ID and username in local storage and trying to get at app.component.ts where profile menu is declared, since app.component.ts initializes starting of my app it is not able to pick up username which was set in login.ts

login.ts:

```
if (login successful) {
    this.storage.set('empid', this.dbempid);
    this.storage.set('empname', this.dbusername);
    this.navCtrl.push(this.dashBoardPage); 
}
```

app.component.ts

```
this.storage.get('empname').then((val) => {
    this.connectedUsername = val;
});
```

app.html

```
{{connectedUsername}}
```

Comment: which storage are you using? also which version of ionic?

Comment: Where you write code for get username in app.component.ts ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are struggling with component communication (Login page needs to tell the containing App about something).  Couple options from my perspective:

1. Make an auth service/provider. Have Login.ts write to a property in that service. Then have app.component.ts and app.html display data from this service (which will be set by the login, whenever that happens).
2. Use events.  Since the app.component.ts loads before the user logs in (Login.ts), once the user successfully logs in the Login.ts page could fire an event.  The app.component.ts file could subscribe to that event, and check storage at that point for the newly saved username.  Ionic has a friendly event system built for you already: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/